# Are syntax and semantic just 2 structures such that one is a model of the other?

Tags: programming-languages, semantics, natural-language-processing, syntax

- The syntax of a language is a structure.
- The semantic of a language is a structure.
- The semantic of a language is a model of its syntax.

And that's all ? The duality syntax/semantic is just model theory applied to languages ?

(A short answer could be ok; I have already read the wikipedia pages !)

Comment: No, that's certainly not all. Syntax is a very concrete representation, and you should be able to make it as precise as you wish. Semantics is the connection to the "real world", but depending on application, the "real world" can be replaced by something more manageable. But the normal case it that even "more manageable" is still vastly more complex than syntax. What is the semantics of C or C++? Does it even exists, is it really needed or useful? Can't one simply defined it via ... (insert your favorite excuse for not dealing with this problem here) ...?

Comment: @ThomasKlimpel It all depends on what you consider is the real world. Syntax is often a lot more real than the semantics. At least you can touch it.

Comment: Syntax is form. Semantics give meaning.

Comment: @ThomasKlimpel It seems to me that your second sentence doesn't match with the rest of your comment. If semantics is close to real world then semantic is concrete (and more complicate) and syntax is a more **abstract** representation (and more simple).

Comment: @Raphael Form and meaning are just names for very similars things. As I understand it, the only difference is that the syntax structure have to be countable.

Comment: I disagree. Take the language of (formal) mathematics, for instance: without semantics, it's all a bunch of symbols. Okay, you can parse expressions into a tree. But that's it. Without semantics, you have no idea what the symbols are supposed to *mean*. Programming languages are another example. Syntax takes you from code to a syntax tree, but you need semantics to create equivalent code in another language.

Comment: @Raphael But if you take W-grammars (see Brian Tompsett answer) the frontier is less clear.

Comment: Programming language folks sometimes have (to my mind) peculiar views. In that area, I think the additional notion of *static semantics* is useful. That said, *of course* you can model form and meaning in the same formalism, if you so desire. I daresay that pain waits down that route, but well. Either way, modelling both at the same time does not mean the concepts are the same. For instance, you can apply any symbol-homomorphism to the syntax and get the same meaning, while clearly form changed  beyond recognition.

Comment: @François Maybe I should have said "practice" instead of "real world". If you want to deal with syntax only on a theoretical level, then that's just fine. But if you try to ignore "practice" for semantics, then you are missing an important point of semantics. Semantics is not very concrete, because three different compilers (say for a workstation, a smartphone, and an embedded device) will interpret the semantics of a language slightly different (just as three different people will), and none of them is necessarily correct or wrong. They just have different context and different priorities.

Comment: @ThomasKlimpel Thus we can say that Syntax is an abstract (general) thing which matches with all the concrete (particular) semantics. I have just commented babou answer about this, may be we can merge the discussions over there.

Comment: @François I was somewhat mislead by the phrasing of your question ... my
mistake. Hence I had to add a new piece of text on top of my already
far too long answer. You may want to look at it, and possibly
comment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am afraid the phrasing of the question misled me (though I did know
better) in first seeing model theory as applying to any two arbitrary
mathematical structures, and being the study of homomorphisms of
mathematical structures.

Actually this is wrong. [Model Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_theory) already contains the idea of
syntax and semantics, more or less as I define it below. It studies
*theories*, which are sets of sentences in a formal language, and
*models* which are interpretation of these sentences in abstract
mathematical structures. This is close to what I call *language*
below, and I guess this is also close to what the author of the question calls
*language*.

So the proper answer to the question is that even model theory has a
concept of syntax and semantics, where syntax is a *theory*, i.e. a
formal representation structure such as a [universal algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_algebra), and
semantics is an interpretation (i.e. a morphism) in some abstract
mathematical domain.

Hence **the "duality syntax/semantic" is already present in model
theory**. There is nothing new on that side.

However, **what may make a difference is the understanding of the word
language**, as it could be interpreted as going beyond what is usually
concerned by the syntactic algebras usually addressed by model theory.

Actually, the question does not define the word language, and it could
be formal languages, programming languages, natural languages, with
some unsaid understanding of what is intended.

So two possible answers could be:

- model theory is the study of languages with their syntax and
  semantics, and there is nothing to add, or
- a language can be defined by an arbitrary syntactic definition
  (meaning a computable structure) and a homomorphic(?) mapping in
  some abstract mathematical structure. The question mark is because
  I fear that the definition of the mapping may raise some issues.

The second view is possibly less formal, or less constrained. Whatever
the case, I am leaving below my initial answer (which corresponds to
the second view), since several of the issues it is addressing may
still be relevant and of interest to computer scientist, even though
the presentation may be debatable from the point of view of model
theory.

It does not bring anything new from a formal point of view, since the study of formal system that are considered in syntax already had to go all the way to Turing computability, in order to address the [Entscheidungsproblem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entscheidungsproblem), and that is as far as we may hope to go in terms of syntax.
I may however help understanding some more practical issues.

*Your comments are welcome, including suggestions to erase my former, more naive, though possibly more intuitive, answer.*

---

---

*The first section is the direct answer to the question. The other two
sections may be skipped. They are attempts to explore some examples or consequences, or some practical
aspects encountered by computer scientists, in particular in the
design of programming languages.*

### Syntax, semantics and languages

The view of the issue as expressed in the question is mainly "OK". My
main criticism though is that **the reference to the concept of
language is critical**, because directly related to the concept of
syntax, not separable from the concept of syntax.

As a consequence, there is something circular, kind of tautological,
about your statement. The question is why do we use this specific
terminology of "*syntax and semantics*" for some models, for some
homomorphically related pairs of structures, and not for others. Where
is the difference? And a correlated question is: **what is a language?**

Clearly there is no restriction on semantics: any topic/structure can
be the object/content of a discourse. Hence, the fundamental
distinction is to be looked for on the syntax side. My own
understanding is that what distinguishes such a homomorphic pair is
the [domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_of_a_function) of the homomorphism: **the syntax structure has to be concrete and
concretely manipulatable**. Basically a syntactic structure is a
finite collection of concrete objects, usually idealized as symbols,
and a finitely defined collection of rules to compose in diverse ways any unboundedly
finite number of copies of these symbols, and to transform such
compositions into others compositions. The word *syntax* comes from
'[Ancient Greek: σύνταξις "coordination" from σύν *syn*, "together,"
and τάξις *táxis*, "an ordering"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax#Etymology)'.

Fundamentally, syntax is physical. The concept of symbol is only a
mean to abstract away the choice of physical instanciation of the
symbols as objects such as sounds, gestures, [glyphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glyph), objects, stones
(which gave us the word *calculus*), electric or magnetic state,
presence and absence of a signal, etc., or composition of other
symbols.

Hence, the theory of syntax is essentially what is better known as the
theory of computation, which is the study of rule based manipulation
of symbols. Whatever we express, transmit, receive, compute, memorize,
analyze, is processed through some syntactic symbolic representation.

But what we are interested in is not the symbolic representations, but
some semantic concepts or objects (possibly themselves physical) that are
intended to be represented by the symbolic compositions at hand. And
the correspondence is defined by the semantic homomorphism into its
semantic [codomain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codomain).

Then, in the most general acceptation of the word, **a language is the
association of a syntax structure and a semantic structure through a
homomorphic mapping**. Or to state it in the terms of the question, it
is a pair of structures such that one is a model of the other, with
the additional requirement that the latter be a syntactic structure.
**But, in order to give such a definition, you must first define what
is a syntactic structure.** And that definition stands on its own,
independently of the concepts of *language* or *semantics*: **Syntax
is the study of finitely defined manipulations (including transmission
and memorization) of unboundedly finite compositions of copies of a
finite set of symbols**. Ot in simpler terms, **syntax concerns the
definition, analysis and manipulation of representations**.  You may
read *computation theory* and *information theory*.

This is in agreement with the concept of homomorphism: the meaning of
the whole is derived from the meaning of the parts. But this is a
meta-remark. I insist less on defining semantics since it seems that
any structure (that makes sense?) can play that role.

### Further remarks

I do not know if the view of linguists on natural language is exactly
the same, or as precise regarding the homomorphic relation, but it
should not be too far from it. The concepts of syntax and semantics
arose from language analysis and logic, which I assume were the same
topic at some point in history (actually diverging pretty late, in the
19th century according to [Wikipedia page on syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax#Early_history)). Still, it seems
that some modern linguists follow somewhat similar views "[*since they regard syntax to be the study of an abstract formal system*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax#Modern_theories)".

The point is that most mathematical domains, abstract concepts, and
other objects of discourse generally elude us, and can only be
contemplated and dealt with through mechanisms to represent them and
(some of) theirs values, i.e. through syntactic representation. In its
simplest form, it can be a pointing finger to represent a direction.

The main characteristic of a syntactic domain is that it is a concrete
representation, finitely defined through some formal system such as
the formal languages dear to computer scientists. But these syntactic
domains, which are very precisely the domain of computation, i.e. of
syntactic transformations, are very limited, as we learn from the
study of computability. For example, they are denumerable, while many
abstract domains we are interested in are not denumerable.

As a consequence, it is often the case that syntax can only represent
a small part of the mathematical domains we study. This is typically
the case for real numbers, almost all of which do not have a (finite)
syntactic representation, the others being the computable reals.

Choosing a data structure to represent the values of some abstract
domain we wish to compute with is just finding an appropriate syntax,
for your semantic problem, whether to express some conceptual semantic
derivation (computation) or to have simpler relation with semantics (semantic morphism),
or to optimize some aspect of communication and memorization
(space. speed, reliability).

For users who want an example, computing the sum of XXVII and XCII, I
mean 11011 and 1011100, is just a manipulation of the digits to get the
representation of a number (119) that is the sum of the numbers
represented by the initial two representations. The positional
notation happens to be easier to manipulate, to be more economical in
space (number and variety of symbols), and to have a simpler way to
express the homomorphism. The syntax changes, the semantics is the
same, and in both correspond to languages to express natural numbers
(well, not quite for Roman numerals).

IMHO (but some of this may be a matter of individual perspective), if
syntax should be only what can be represented and manipulated,
semantics can be any mathematical domain, or more generally any
abstract domain of discourse, including the domains used for
syntax. Hence you can have a theory of syntax where you study
syntactic representation systems. Formal language theory is nothing
else.

Note that the the idea of a syntac-semantic *duality* should not
induce the idea that there is some sort of symmetry between syntax and
semantics.

### Syntax and semantics in computer science practice

It is true that we often pretend to address semantic issues, for
example when defining formally the semantics of a programming language
$L$. But that may be seen as an abuse. What we really do is use a standard
language $S$ that is supposed to have an accepted semantics and define
the semantics of $L$ in terms of the semantics of $S$. The difficulty
is that we can never access semantics directly, but only through some
syntactic proxy, even when the semantics is itself syntactic in
nature. This is why we use metalanguages such as [Backus-Naur Form (BNF)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form).

There are however various mathematical techniques to define semantic
domains. Among these techniques, you have the definition of syntactic
models where the syntax (possibly up to quotient by some equivalence
relation) is its own model. Actually, one of the major contribution of
Dana Scott to computer science was to conceive non-syntactic models of
lambda-calculus which is (initially at least) a purely syntactic theory (see for example
[Continuation Models for the Lambda Calculus With Constructors](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S157106611200062X),
B. Petit (2012).

A characteristic of most mathematical theories is that they may have
many models, including non-standard models. "[*A non-standard model is a
model of a theory that is not isomorphic to the intended model (or
standard model)*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-standard_model)". That also applies to syntactic theories. Actually,
non-standard interpretation of languages is a very fruitful area of
research in computer science, related to [abstract interpretation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_interpretation), type
analysis, flow analysis, [partial evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_evaluation) and many other approaches
to program analysis.  To take a very trivial, purely syntactic
example, a non-standard interpretation of a program can be a
pretty-printed version of that program. A type checker is usually an
abstract interpretation of the program.

As a consequence, it is clear that the chosen syntax may not capture,
express, all the properties of the intended semantic domain. However,
anything that is considered as syntactically correct must have some
associated semantics through the semantic morphism, even if it is some
special error value. But it is improper, though often done, to state
that the syntax is defined by a context-free grammars, and then
consider programs with undeclared variables as being incorrect. It
cannot be syntactically incorrect for such a reason, because CF
grammars cannot check variable declarations. And I would not know what
it means to be semantically incorrect, other than being possibly a
special error value of the semantic structure.

The dream of programming language designers or implementor is that any
program that can only fail, or that can fail in some specific way,
should be syntactically incorrect. Hence, they have been increasing
the descriptive power of syntax to include as much checking as
possible, limited only by computability constraints. This did lead to
the use of Turing complete formalisms, of which [van Wijngaarden's
W-grammars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_Wijngaarden_grammar) are an example. But this is a [pipe dream](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pipe_dream). Computability
theory tells us that semantic properties of syntactically expressed
functions cannot be checked syntactically, as soon as the language has
Turing power, which we usually expected in programming languages.

In practice, this checking for intrinsic correctness (i.e. independent
of problem specification), or for properties to be used, is often
performed in compilers (or in formal semantic definitions) by what is
called [static semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_language#Static_semantics). Being purely computational, static semantics can be as well considered as part of the syntax.

In the case of programming languages, the semantic domain is a
computation domain.  Given that we allow Turing complete formalisms to
express the syntax, it becomes possible for the syntax to express
completely the semantics. But developing this angle is getting far away
from the original question. Still, this is the main reason why the distinction between syntax and semantics is so difficult to make precise in programming languages.  This may also be the reason why universal Turing machines are possible.

A last point is that defining the semantics as a structure that is a
model of the syntax may not be enough. It could be a model in several
different ways. So it is essential to include the morphism in the
description of the semantics. That is typically what is done with
denotational semantics of programming languages, and a lot of other
formal systems.

<sub>*Note: This was rather complex and hard to write. If you are to
criticize it, I would appreciate explicit and precise comments. It
would also be useful to other users. Thank you.*</sub>

Comment: Thanks, your answer is helpful. There is just a thing I would like discuss : It seems to me that semantics is concrete, particular, whereas syntax is more abstract, more general (it matches with many semantics). For example, if you use a language to speak about the vehicle park of a society, may be the semantics of "C12" is a red car, you can touch it. But the syntax "C12" is very abstract and could appoint anything in other contexts.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Trying to give you a proper answer is a lot more work than I initially bargained for. I am in the process of a complete rewriting of my answer. It is not too far from finished. To answer your question, the abstraction is not in C12, but in the semantic morphism. **Syntax is always concrete**, both an advantage (manipulatable) and a major drawback (Turing limitations), while semantics may or may not be. The central issue is that this concerns languages, and the discourse can address semantics only through syntax. So that the semantic morphism plays an essential role.

Comment: The re-working is excellent. I was tempted to expand my all-too-brief answer to embrace what you had started, but you have done that for me. This area was part of my long-ago Phd work and it is nice to see it feature in an answer to small question on SE...  :-)

Comment: Wow, an excellent exposition! You wrote: "What we really do is use a standard language $S$ that is supposed to have an accepted semantics and define the semantics of $L$ in terms of the semantics of $S$." But often the intended semantics is only explained, not precisely defined. From my point of view, even the intended semantics of ZFC set theory is not precisely defined, because this is not really possible.

Comment: @BrianTompsett Thanks. The problem is however that I started on false premises. Hence I had to add another, more correct answer on top of what I already had (far too long). I should have known, and actually knew better ... but so it goes. I would appreciate any comment you might have. Reading on vW Grammar was rejuvenating, though I am no longer really able to understand them. I just fell on my old copy of the Algol 68 report (which I did read, a long time ago).

Comment: @ThomasKlimpel Thanks. As I am saying above, this was unfortunately
written on some false premises. So you may want to have a look at the
text I added on top (the rest did not change) and possibly
comment. Regarding your last comment, I agree that this is not quite a
satisfactory part. My main excuse is that the answer is already too
long. However, there are semantic structures that can be defined
precisely (up to isomorphism). My feeling is that this is particularly
true of computable structures which are all we really care about in
the context of programming languages.

Comment: @babou Do you think that the "duality" syntax/semantics is based on (cartesian) dualism ? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dualism_%28philosophy_of_mind%29

Comment: @François I guess model theory became a necessity when mathematicians became
aware that axiomatisation was not enough to tell the story. It seems
to be fairly recent (a century and some) but I have no precise
data. I doubt cartesian dualism has anything to do with it. Imho,
dualism is more like a negation of it, since the only thing on wich we
have a handle is the syntax, and we never have a trustable perception
unless it has a syntax. I do not believe in dualism, and to me
consciousness is a phenomenon akin to reflection in programming
languages resulting from evolutionary modeling ability.

Answer (score 4):

It all very much depends on how you model these concepts where syntax end and semantics start. When the syntax is described using a context free grammar, then there are aspects of the language not expressed in that model so we say those aspects are the semantics.

However, there are many other ways of expressing (or modelling) the syntax of the language. Take [W-grammars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_Wijngaarden_grammar) for example. You can define the totality of the language in one grammar and the distinction between the semantic and the syntactic component is less clear. The book [*Grammars for Programming Languages* by Cleaveland and Uzgalis](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0444001875) contains a good introduction and some nice examples, one of which I show here:

```
N :: i ; Ni .
EMPTY :: .
NETY :: N; EMPTY.
RADIX :: iii iii iii i .
EXP :: iiN.

fermat : EXP pr N1, equal symbol,
         EXP pr N2, plus symbol,
         EXP pr N3,
         where N1 is N2N3.

N1 pr N2 : N3 number, power symbol, N1 number,
           where N2 is N3 to the N1 power.

where N1 is N2 to the NETY i power :
           where N3 is N2 to the NETY power,
           where N1 is N3 times N2;
           where N1 is N2, where NETY is EMPTY.

where NETY1 N is N is N time NETY2 i :
           where NETY1 is N times NETY2 ;
           where NETY1 NETY2 is EMPTY.

where NETY is NETY : EMPTY.

N1 number : N1 token; N2 number, NETY token,
          where N3 is N2 times RADIX,
          where N1 is NETY N3.
```

This defines the syntax of equations which obey the proviso of [Fermat's last theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_Last_Theorem), complete with the definition of arithmetic and the mathematics involved....

Comment: Thanks, your answer is helpful. I will learn about W-grammars.